# Which is Apache latest version?

Tags: apache-http-server

2.4.7 as in [httpd apache site](http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi)

OR

2.4.9 as in [apachelounge site](http://www.apachelounge.com/download/)

Any idea?

Comment: What on earth is apachelounge??

Comment: Both links say that 2.4.9 is the latest stable release

Comment: The reason the author thought 2.4.7 was the lastest on the `apachelounge.com` is because he was looking at the `VC9` release files which of course is sort of silly when `VC10` and `VC11` offer significant improvements. You should base any decision about what release you should be using based on the content on the main project website. The other website is only about VC compatible releases.  **Its also trivial to compile it yourself using VC9**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to  [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi) the latest stable release is 2.4.9 (released 2014-03-17). This should always be your first port of call for this sort of information.

I am not entirely sure why you think 2.4.7 is the latest release. The link you provided is the same as mine and doesn't list this version.

Comment: Sorry guys, this is so bizarre. My browser showed me 2.4.7 at "http://httpd.apache.org/" and at "http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi". After I read your replays and several refreshes it changed to 2.4.9, caching????

Comment: Probably cache. All sorted now :)